# Skype for business - how to change the received files default path?

Tags: skype-for-business

How to change the default path of the Skype for business's received files.

Where can I find the settings to change the default path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Skype for business, by default the received files are stored in the path `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Received Files`.

To change the default path, you need to click the "gear icon" for "Options" menu.

> [image: Options]

In the list of options, navigate to **File Saving** option. In that **Save to:** box, you can find the default path. By clicking on the Browse... button, you may change it to your required folder path.

> [image: File Saving]